# ¿como puedo hacer para que un contenedor o imagen cambie su tamaño con los distintos breakpoints usando flex-layout de Angular?

Tags: angular, height, flex-layout, width

Estoy comenzando a entender flex-layout de Angular, pero hasta ahora no he visto como pudiera hacer para que un contenedor o una imagen cambie de tamaño dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla?

Ejemplo:

```html
    <div class="cont1" style="height: 400px; width: 400px">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    </div>
```

y quisiera que al llegar al `breakpoint xs`, tuviese un height de 200px y width de 200px , en el `breakpoint sm` tuviese un height de 300px y width de 300px y así sucesivamente. ¿como podría lograr esto?

lo único que se me ha ocurrido es usar media queries en el CSS pero no estoy muy seguro de si es una buena práctica eso, sería buena práctica usar media queires en el CSS cuándo estás usando Flex-Layout?

Gracias a todos de antemano,

Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo mejor es usar media queries, si es una buena practica y además muy común. Para que la implementación sea mas robusta lo recomendable crear un archivo con los breakpoints que manejarás para que el comportamiento de tu página sea consistente en diferentes tamaños.

Por ejemplo:

```
    $break-points: (
        xs: (
                min-width: 0,
                max-width: 575px,
        ),
        sm: (
                min-width: 576px,
                max-width: 767px,
        ),
        md: (
                min-width: 768px,
                max-width: 991px,
        ),
        lg: (
                min-width: 992px,
                max-width: 1199px,
        ),
        xl: (
                min-width: 1200px,
                max-width: 4000px,
        );
)
```

Y lo implementas de la siguiente forma:

```
@media (max-width: map-get(map_get($break-points, xs), max-width)) {
    .cont1 {
       height: 200px;
       width: 200px;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hola David. No sabía nada de map-get , esto está solo en SAAS o también en CSS? actualmente no trabajo con SAAS (aun que se que es esencial en estos momentos).

Comment: Hola Julian, perdona, hasta ahora puedo responderte. Si es solo para SASS, es recomendable que lo uses, pero puedes evitar el map-get creando variables estáticas, solo que con el map-get se tiene un poco mas ordenado todo.